# Safe updating object in rest api

Tags: java, rest

I created rest api:

GET metohd on /api/address returns address for currently logged user. Then user can edit some data and send edited json by POST to /api/address. But user also can just send preapred json to rest api omitting UI.

For example:

```
{id:2, street: Madison, flatNumber: 14}
```

Then in AddressService:

```
public void updateUser(AddressDto address) {
  repository.findOneById(address.getId()).ifPresent(a -> {
    a.setFlatNumber(address.getFlatNumber());
    respository.update(a);
  });
}
```

But user can send prepared json with different id. And edit address that doesn't belong to him. How to prevent that situation?

I want to make sure if users can only update theirs data. Should I everytime check if entity is in relation with logged user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the `updateUser` method, modify the code to pull the record based on the user.

```
repostiory.findAddressByUserAndId(user, address.getId())
```

And if you only need one address for each user, consider useing the useras the Id of the address record.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Acctually address entity is only simple example. In my application I have more complex entities' relationships. Idea that you proposed is good. Honestly I hoped that there is more elegant solution. So if any better soluton won't appear in some time, I'll accept this answer.